# laravel - Updating row changes created_at column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I update my row with the query below, it changes not only the updated_at column for the row, but also the created_at column. Why? How can I prevent this so that it only changes the updated_at column

```
Post::where('id', Input::get('post_id'))
->where('user_id', getUserID())
->update(array('message' => Input::get('message')));
```

Comment: How does  'Post' model looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Laravel documentation at
[Insert-update-delete](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

You can use following method to perform update

```
$x = Post::find(Input::get('post_id')); // may need to use intval()
$x->message = Input::get('message');
$x->save();
```

This should update the record with only updating 'updated_at' timestamp.