# laravel 5.2 updated_at doesnt work

Tags: laravel, timestamp

When i do an update() or save() statement on my model then it's always updating **created_at** field. There is not even an **updated_at** field in the model.
in the model i use already timestamps see code below.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



    class Restaurants extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'table';

        protected $fillable = ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6'];

        public $timestamps = true;
```

When i search on the internet I only see how to ignore updated_at

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Did you use Laravel 5.2 ??

Comment: Please show us how you use update and save on your controller

Comment: yes its 5.2
$order_update_conftime->roConfirmationTime = $conformationtime;
      
    $order_update_conftime->update();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel changes created\_at on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673729/laravel-changes-created-at-on-update)

Comment: What is the problem here? Is there any error? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Please post the code you use to update this model

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673729/laravel-changes-created-at-on-update
how could i do the second option ?

Comment: Romnick Susa i want to use updated_at field

Comment: In your restaurant migration remove `->timestamp()` and add this `->timestamp(created_at)->useCurrent();
->timestamp(updated_at)->useCurrent();`

Comment: there is already a file under database/migrations/2016_03_01_051123_create_restaurants_table.php

Comment: Should i edit this file database/migrations/2016_03_01_051123_create_restaurants_tab‌​le.php

Comment: Show us your database/migrations/2016_03_01_051123_create_restaurants_tab‌​‌​le.ph and sample controller that uses your model

Comment: https://ibb.co/bWMDjv