# Update using Laravel: created_at is updated when updating record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The update functionality is doing fine with the below codes. Where I update the `status` field as `0`. The default value of that field is `1`. It works fine, but the `created_at` field also updates whenever this function is used. It should be the `updated_at` field that is being updated not the `created_at`.

In my `notification_records` table I have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

Where the `created_at` data type is `timestamp()` this field is used if there's new created notification records and the `updated_at` field is for modification only

```
public function notification(Request $request){
$company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;
DB::connection('mysql')->select("UPDATE notification_records SET status = '0' WHERE company_id = '".$company_id."' AND id = '".$request->ind."'");
}
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever the function is being used the only field that will update the value of the field between `created_at` and `updated_at` is the `updated_at` only. Is there possible way to do it with the above codes?

Comment: it's not good practice to write raw sql query when there is other options available for same either by query builder method or eloquent method also you in your table structure if you didn't set created_at Attributes as on update currenttimestamp then it will not update it also you can pass date in your updated_at field when you are hitting youe function

Comment: I removed the "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and it works fine now. Also I added the default value of these timestamps. Actually I'm using different join of table that's why I preferred to use the classic sql query than using eloquent or builder method

Comment: you can user query builder method for that( different join of table  ) too but it okay , i am just saying it's not a good practice . It's not like you have to do it or not

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Noted. I'll to learn those methods once I get a new project. Since I already started the project with this kind of coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue in laravel 5.2 
You can mitigate this by removing and readding the timestamps as follows:
Instead of `$table->timestamps()`;

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default('0000-00-00 00:00');
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default('0000-00-00 00:00');
```

See here for the question: [Laravel changes created_at on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673729/laravel-changes-created-at-on-update)

The solution is referenced from here

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/150